# Is there a PHP markdown parser supporting Telegram's syntax?

Tags: library, php, markdown

Telegram's markdown syntax is slightly different from that used elsewhere.

Namely it uses a single * for bold, and a single _ for italic.

(which, by the way, is much smarter)

Is there a PHP parser supporting this syntax?